# What does 'with the rolling and the heaving and the you make me sick' line mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I've been watching Simpsons and one guy said, "with the rolling and the heaving and the you make me sick".

What does that mean?

Context: father of the geek scientist couldn't stand him, because the father was a he-man, who "worked on the atom bomb by day, slept with Marilyn Monroe by night, and sold secrets to the Russians at lunch". When the dad was getting ready for a scientific trip on a ship, his son told him that he don't want to go with him because he's getting seasick taking the shower.

And in the end the geek added "nauseous but clean".

And his father responded: "Clean but nauseous". With the rolling and the heaving and the you make me sick

Comment: There might be some "double-meaning punning" here - "rolling" could refer to *contemptuous rolling of eyes upwards*, and "heaving" to *vomiting*, as well as both verbs referring to waves and ocean swell. And there's the figurative reference to *You make me sick = I find you disgustingly disappointing*, as well as *literally* vomiting die to sea-sickness. Also note that it's a regular feature of at least *some* Simpsons characters (esp Nerdelbaum Frink Jr) to use the rather peculiar idiomatic form *[What] **with the X and the Y and the Z*** with "syntactically quirky" terms for X, Y, Z.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for such detailed answer! I'm still having problems undesrtanding those puns 100% maybe when I'm fluent I will. And by the way it was nice to see that you're familiar with Simpsons (even more than me who've watched a lot of episodes in my life)

Comment: Not so familiar that I coud just type **Nerdelbaum Frink Jr** from memory! I had to look him up by googling **simpsons nerd scientist!**

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see

Comment: @FumbleFingers you can write your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some "double-meaning punning" here - "rolling" could refer to *contemptuous rolling of eyes upwards*, and "heaving" to *vomiting*, as well as both verbs referring to waves and ocean swell.

And there's the figurative reference to *You make me sick = I find you disgustingly disappointing*, as well as *literally* vomiting due to sea-sickness.

Also note that it's a regular feature of at least *some* Simpsons characters (esp Nerdelbaum Frink Jr) that they use the already "peculiar" idiomatic form *[What] **with the X and the Y and the Z*** with syntactically and / or semantically "quirky" terms for X, Y, Z